# No numbering environment conflicting with IEEE

Tags: ieeetran

So I made a `remark` environment, which is used just once, and I do not want to get it numbered. To use `\newtheorem*` command I need to activate `amsthm` package....but then this package is making changes to `IEEEtran` style by making many other things as italics.....
Is there way I can manually number a environment, so that i can just use spacebar to number

```
%\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}  % Comment this line out
                                                          % if you need a4paper
%\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{ieeeconf}      % Use this line for a4
                                                          % paper
%\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
%\documentclass[journal,12pt,draftclsnofoot,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}

%\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

       % This command is only
                                                          % needed if you want to
                                                          % use the \thanks command
%\overrideIEEEmargins

% *** GRAPHICS RELATED PACKAGES ***
%

% *** MATH PACKAGES ***
%

%\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}   
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
%\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts      
%% INFOCOM 2013 addition:

\makeatletter
\def\ps@headings{%
\def\@oddhead{\mbox{}\scriptsize\rightmark \hfil \thepage}%
\def\@evenhead{\scriptsize\thepage \hfil \leftmark\mbox{}}%
\def\@oddfoot{}%
\def\@evenfoot{}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}










\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,graphicx,charter,latexsym}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
%\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{observation}{Observation}
% *** SPECIALIZED LIST PACKAGES ***
%


\allowdisplaybreaks[4]
\usepackage{bbm}

% *** ALIGNMENT PACKAGES ***
%

\begin{document}
\title{\bf{xx}}
\author{xx
\thanks{xx}
xx
}
\maketitle

\begin{remark}
AA
\end{remark}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seemed you had pasted the code twice, so I removed one of them. To highlight code, select it and click the button marked with `{}`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way: just redefine the `rem` counter to remove the space between the label and the colon.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}
\renewcommand{\therem}{\unskip}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{thm}
\lipsum*[3]
\end{thm}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{rem}
\lipsum*[3]
\end{rem}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]